# Python using combinations to sum values in a tuple in a list in a dictionary?

Tags: python, tuples, combinations

I am trying to sum a combination of values from a list of tuples in a dictionary.  For example, my dictionary contains:

```
dict = {1: [(2, 2), (4, 3), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 3)], 2: [(4, 1), (5, 3), (1, 2)],...}
```

and goes on for multiple entries.  I'm trying to sum the second value of the tuples for each entry in as many combinations that sum to a maximum of 4.  So for entry 1, the desired output would be:

```
{1: [(2, 6, 3), (2, 7, 3), (4, 6, 4), (4, 7, 4), (6, 7, 2), (8, 6, 4), (8, 7, 4)]
```

Where the third value in this tuple is the sum of the combinations of the second value of the previous tuples, and the first and second values of this tuple are the associated first values of the previous tuples.

I have tried the following code:

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    object1 = key
    mylist = value
    for tup in mylist:
         object2 = tup[0]
         pair = tup[1]
         combo = itertools.combinations(tup[1],2)
         sum = {k:sum(j for _,j in v) for k,v in combo}
         if sum <= 4:
             print(sum)
```

And I get the error

```
'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

I think my error stems from "combo" and possibly my use of itertools.  I am unsure if I just need to fix this section of my code or if I am way off base in my approach.

Comment: I can't seem to make sense of the problem. The error is from attempting to iterate over a non iterable. But the code doesn't appear to take the input you have given.

Comment: What is `mylist`?

Comment: _"I think my error stems from "combo""_ The traceback would indicate what line the error is raised from, I think it would be relevent to the question please.

Comment: There are at least a couple of bugs in your code that will cause a problem, although not the one you think. So, you've assigned the name `sum` the result of your `dict` comprehension. That means `sum <= 4` will throw an error, and even if that didn't, the next time you try to use `sum` the *function* you wont be able to because `sum` is now a dictionary

Comment: Also, if  `tup` is a tuple of `numpy.float64` objects, then `tup[0]` is some number, which isn't iterable, which will throw the error you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with `itertools.combinations`, but you have to pass it the right arguments. :) You need to pass it the list of tuples so it can make the pairs of tuples. You *could* do this with comprehensions, but I think using traditional `for` loops makes it easier to read.

As others have mentioned, there are other problems with your code, apart from not passing the right things to `combinations`. The main one being that you're assigning a dictionary to the name `sum`, which shadows the `sum` built-in function that you're also trying to use. And you also attempt to compare that dictionary with the integer 4, that doesn't make a lot of sense. :)

Anyway, here's some code that does what you want. Note that in your expected output you messed up the last two tuples: `(8, 6, 4)` and `(8, 7, 4)` should be `(6, 8, 4)` and `(7, 8, 4)`, respectively.

```
from itertools import combinations

a = {
    1: [(2, 2), (4, 3), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 3)], 
    2: [(4, 1), (5, 3), (1, 2)],
}

new_dict = {}

for k, seq in a.items():
    c = []
    for (u,v), (x,y) in combinations(seq, 2):
        total = v + y
        if total <= 4:
            c.append((u, x, total))
    new_dict[k] = c

for k, seq in new_dict.items():
    print(k, seq)
```

**output**

```
1 [(2, 6, 3), (2, 7, 3), (4, 6, 4), (4, 7, 4), (6, 7, 2), (6, 8, 4), (7, 8, 4)]
2 [(4, 5, 4), (4, 1, 3)]
```

`combinations(seq, 2)` yields pairs of tuples, and we can unpack those tuples into their individual numbers with

```
for (u,v), (x,y) in combinations(seq, 2):
```

We *could* have done something like

```
for t0, t1 in combinations(seq, 2):
```

and then unpacked the `t0` and `t1` tuples in a separate step, or just used indexing to get their items. Eg,

```
for t0, t1 in combinations(seq, 2):
    total = t0[1] + t1[1]
    if total <= 4:
        c.append((t[0], t[1], total))
```

But I think the previous way is less cluttered.

---

But if you insist on doing it all with comprehensions, you can:

```
new_dict = {k: [(u, x, v+y) for (u,v), (x,y) in combinations(seq, 2) if v+y <= 4]
    for k, seq in a.items()}
```

Note that this is less efficient than the previous versions because it computes `v+y` twice for every combination that passes the `v+y <= 4` test.